# How to do contact routing in sensu core same like we do on sensu enerprise?

Tags: handler, monitoring, sensu, mailing

I am trying to use the contact routing so that i can use it to make my mail handler to mail different customers form a single mail id, as right now sensu core allows for only one customer to mail, or is there any way that i can do this without setting up contact routing. Contact routing is a feature that comes in sensu enterprise and not in sensu core.

Answer (score 0):

There is sensu-plugins-mailer that implement routing by contact which you can put in client or check scope:
https://github.com/sensu-plugins/sensu-plugins-mailer.
There is some other related feature in Sensu - filters which you can use in handler so handler executes only for this filter. Filter itself you can determine depends on client custom attributes or check custom attribute.

Have you found better ways to solve this?